# How to install and setup Irvine library in vs code 2019 for assembly language

Tags: installation, masm, irvine32

Why **Irvine** library is not Linking in **VS code 2019** (blue version) for **assembly** language

I tried to setup Irvine library in VS code 2019 ( blue version) for assembly language. Everything is okay but when I wrote program that print 1 to 15 but it shows errors like Irvine is not linked

Answer (score 1):

I will suppose you're using masm32 as your assembler, to properly set up your MASM project with Irvine32 in Visual Studio, follow these steps:

**Download and Prepare Irvine32 Library:**

- Download Irvine32 library from https://github.com/meixinchoy/Irvine-library.
- Unzip and move the folder to C:\Irvine.

**Check Build Customization:**

- Right-click your project in Visual Studio, select Build Dependencies > Build Customizations.
- Ensure the MASM option (.targets, .props) is checked.

[Build Customizations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBvwh.png)

**Set .asm File Properties:**

- In Solution Explorer, right-click your .asm file, choose Properties and confirm Item Type is set to Microsoft Macro Assembler.

[File Item Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmYyq.png)

**Configure Build Settings:**

- Right-click your project, select Properties.
- Under Microsoft Macro Assembler > General, set Include Paths to C:\Irvine.

[Include Paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWCwn.png)

- In Linker > General, set Additional Library Directories to C:\Irvine.

[Additional Library Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiTff.png)

- In Linker > Input, add Irvine32.lib to Additional Dependencies.

[Additional Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSpY7.png)